# select dropdown data-max-option through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am generating a select dropdown throgh jquery and setting the attribute data-max-option='9'.i don't want to allow user to select more than 9 options.how can i do this.data-max-option not working

user can select category and subcategory.default one category is selected while doing the registration by user.so if category is one than user can select six subcategories.if user is selecting categories more than one than i want to allow user to select nine subcategories.so i am using a jquery function on change of category i am generating subcategories dropdown again with data-max-option='9'
data-max-option not working

Answer (score 0):

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9CkG/76/) for working example.

```
$("#s").on("change", function()
{
    var msg = $("#msg");

    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++)
    {
        var option = this.options[i];

        option.selected ? count++ : null;

        if (count > 9)
        {
            option.selected = false;
            option.disabled = true;

            msg.html("Please select only 9 options.");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this one with jquery as well.

> ```
> $('#dropdown').on("click", "option", function ()
> {
>     if ($(this).parent().val().length > 9) {
>        alert("Max 9 values at a time");
>        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
>     }
> });
> ```